# How to make CFLAGS work with the dash shell?

Tags: environment-variables, dash-shell

My impression is that while setting the CFLAGS variable is effective when bash is the default shell, it doesn't make an effect with dash (the Debian Almquist shell).

First of all please correct me if my observation is wrong.

Secondly (if my observation is right), how can I get a global CFLAGS variable effectively go through dash?

I've set the variable in `~/.profile` like this:

```
export CFLAGS=-march=native
```